# Phone number input format

Tags: html, css, angular

I am using angular and I want an input that displays the text format `614-123-1234`.
I don't know exactly how to do it, I found something made in jQuery that could help me but I wasn't allowed to install it on my project

My input:

```html
<input type='number' onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==10) return false;"
 class="input" formControlName="cel" id="cel" name="cel">
```

I want something like this

[image]

Comment: no it does not work

Answer (score 3):

You can install `ngx-mask` package and then specify your ideal mask like this:

```
mask="(000) 000-000"

< input type="text" mask="(000) 000-000" />
```

**Install** **`ngx-mask`**

```
$ npm i ngx-mask
```

**Quickstart**

Import `ngx-mask` module in your Angular app.

With default mask config options:

```
import { NgxMaskModule, IConfig } from 'ngx-mask'

export const options: Partial<null|IConfig> | (() => Partial<IConfig>) = null;

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NgxMaskModule.forRoot(),
  ],
})
```

More about the usage of the `ngx-mask` package is addressed [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask).

Comment: do I have to make any import?

Comment: because it didnt worked

Comment: @Edgar you have to make this import `NgxMaskModule` on your module.

Comment: No, at the end I used jquery and it worked perfectlly